# Python3 flask_socketio and node. js socket. IO how to establish the connection correctly?

Tags: node.js, websocket, flask-socketio

I am building an App server with Python3, and the front end is done with node. js and socket. IO to connect with the back end.
A Python Flask framework is used for the back-end; similarly, a socketio and the front-end are used for connection, but the connection fails
Attempts to change the socketio version were not successful.

====================Here is the python server-side code======================

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, Namespace
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


class APINamespace(Namespace):

    def on_test(self, data):
        print(str(data))
        emit('message', {'data': 'received ' + data['data'] + '!!!'})


socketio.on_namespace(APINamespace('/api'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

======================Here is the HTML test code=======================

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Socket.IO Chat Example</title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="socket.io.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var opts = {
                'reconnection':false,
                'force new connection': true,
                'transports':['websocket', 'polling']
            };
            var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',opts);

            socket.on('message', function() {
                $('#log').append('<br>connect<br>');
                socket.emit('test', {'account': 'user1','name':'user1'});
            });


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div><p id="log">这里显示信息<br></p></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I envision the back end actually printing out the data that comes from the front end{'account': 'user1','name':'user1'}

When the web page opens, however, the back-end console will only print this message

> (3039) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 1707)127.0.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2019 14:01:10] "GET/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 122 0.000404

The front console prints an error message that the handshake failed

> socket.io.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Comment: You need to enable extra logging on the server to know what was the reason for the 400 error. Add `engineio_logger=True` to your SocketIO object constructor.

Comment: @Miguel  Thanks for your help. After I add engineio_logger=True, I print out these things, but I feel these things are not very useful. ``` [sid]: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'd08e4a6826fc40069de629c79ba56335', 'u
pgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
[sid]: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
[sid]: Received request to upgrade to websocket
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2019 15:10:16] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
[sid]: Client is gone, closing socket
 ```

Comment: The "client is gone" indicates that the regular ping/pong packets aren't being exchanged at the regular interval. This can be because the client is not sending pings, or because the server is blocked and cannot process them. Based on experience, the more likely problem is the latter, so you should check what you are doing in the server and make sure nothing that you do is blocking the server.

Comment: @Miguel Yes, there is no communication between the front end and the server. Do you mean that the server is blocked and cannot handle them? Is this a permission problem?

Comment: No, it's not permissions. The server is doing a blocking operation, which are not allowed in an asynchronous application. Remember that this is just a guess based on what I've seen others stumble on, I have no way to know if this is the problem.